# No se crea el trigger instalable mediante "ScriptApp.newTrigger "

Tags: google-apps-script

He creado dos scripts en *Google Apps Script* con el mismo fin en un *standalone*, con la finalidad de crear un ***trigger*** instalable en una hoja de cálculo, pero tras ejecutar el código, no puedo ver el *trigger* en la interfaz del editor de código de la hoja.

Primera opción:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1gcO5jsX5j53WQz6xxxxxxxxxx9gfWRs5zTlc");

var myTrigger = ScriptApp.newTrigger("onFormSubmit")
 .forSpreadsheet(ss)
 .onFormSubmit()
 .create();
```

Segunda opción:

```
var myTrigger = ScriptApp.newTrigger("onFormSubmit")
 .forSpreadsheet("1gcO5jsX5j53WQz6xxxxxxxxxx9gfWRs5zTlc")
 .onFormSubmit()
 .create();
```

¿Por qué pasa esto?

Answer (score 0):

> Nota: Esta es una respuesta parcial que incluye contenido que usualmente se publica como comentario, pero se ha publicado como respuesta, como excepción por la extensión y formato.

Los datos provistos en la pregunta, no son suficientes para saber qué es lo que está pasando.

1. Falta mencionar si se a creado el script con nombre onFormSubmit ya que el newTrigger sólo crea el activador, no el script.
2. Falta mencionar si se ha comprobado que el script a ser llamado por el activador se ejecute sin problemas.
3. Falta mencionar si ocurre o no un mensaje de error.